# How do i write JOOQ select query for the following MSSQL query?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jooq

How do I convert below select query from MSSQL to JOOQ format?

MySql query:

```
SELECT group_concat(AUF.AcLineId )
FROM AcHeader as AH 
INNER JOIN AcDetails AS AD 
  ON AD.AcHeaderId = AH.AcHeaderId 
INNER JOIN AcUserField AS AUF 
  ON AUF.AcLineId = AD.AcLineId 
  AND AUF.FieldNo = 1 
WHERE  AH.Company = 1 AND AH.AccountNo = 190000 AND AH.Status IN ('C', 'D')
```

Jooq query:

```
dslContext.select(AUF.AcLineId)
          .from(AcHeader)
          .Join(AcDetails)
            .on(AcDetails.AcHeaderId.equal(AcHeader.AcHeaderId))
          .Join(AcUserField )
            .on(AcUserField.AcLineId.equal(AcDetails.AcLineId))
            .and(AcUserField.FieldNo.equal())
          .Where(AcHeader.Company=1)
          .and(AcHeader=AccountNo=190000).and(Status.in("'C','D'")).fetch()
```

I think moreover completed, but here i am getting struggle to form group_concat.
If have idea, pls share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ supports MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT()` function natively as [`DSL.groupConcat()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#groupConcat-org.jooq.Field-). Here's your corrected query with comments:

```
// Don't forget, of course:
import org.jooq.impl.DSL;
```

And then

```
// Use DSL.groupConcat() here
dslContext.select(DSL.groupConcat(AcUserField.AcLineId))
          .from(AcHeader)

          // Lower-case join()
          .join(AcDetails)
            .on(AcDetails.AcHeaderId.equal(AcHeader.AcHeaderId))

          // Lower-case join()
          .join(AcUserField)
            .on(AcUserField.AcLineId.equal(AcDetails.AcLineId))

          // Forgot to pass the parameter "1"
            .and(AcUserField.FieldNo.equal(1))

          // Lower-case where() and use .equal() or .eq() rather than a Java assignment "="
          .where(AcHeader.Company.equal(1))
          .and(AcHeader.AccountNo.equal(190000))

          // List values in in(...) predicate individually, don't put them all
          // in a single string.
          .and(AcHeader.Status.in("C", "D")).fetch()
```

Optionally, if you prefer to use aliased versions of your tables, you can do so:

```
AcHeader AH = AcHeader.as("AH");
AcDetails AD = AcDetails.as("AD");
AcUserField AUF = AcUserField.as("AUF");

dslContext.select(DSL.groupConcat(AUF.AcLineId))
          .from(AH)
          .join(AD)
            .on(AD.AcHeaderId.equal(AcHeader.AcHeaderId))
          .join(AUF)
            .on(AUF.AcLineId.equal(AD.AcLineId))
            .and(AUF.FieldNo.equal(1))
          .where(AH.Company.equal(1))
          .and(AH.AccountNo.equal(190000))
          .and(AH.Status.in("C", "D")).fetch()
```

Comment: @user3091530: What are you missing? The method is linked to the Javadoc... I'll add the required import statement to the answer, just in case